# Using WSL through CMDER in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cmder

I have setup WSL in CMDER through `settings->Startup->{WSL::bash}` and also made it my default shell, so whenever I open CMDER it starts in WSL.

I integrated CMDER into VSCODE using https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-VS-Code-Integration and it is working. But the CMDER version opening inside VSCODE is not the default WSL shell.

How can I setup CMDER with WSL as shell, inside VSCODE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I got the WSL shell with CMDER in VSCODE by adding the following in settings.

```
{
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "path\\to\\cmder\\vendor\\conemu-maximus5\\ConEmu\\wsl\\wslbridge.exe"
}
```

CMDER tab shows `wslbridge.exe` when I open WSL shell in CMDER. So I searched for `wslbridge.exe` inside CMDER folder and added the path in VSCODE settings and it worked.

I am not sure if this is the perfect solution or if this causes any issues in the future but it works for now.